# Mysterious span appearing in HTML for react code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, coffeescript, react-rails

I am using `coffeescript` with `react-rails` gem. In the `measure.js.coffee`, there is no span present in the coffee code, but when the HTML is getting painted a mysterious ghost span is appearing. Below is a screenshot of code and HTML generated by it.[image]
[image]

In my code, there is no span in between `carousel-mImages` and `mtag-images`. Is it because of the `reactCSSTransitionGroup = React.createFactory(React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup)`

Comment: Which version of React do you use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` is a wrapper around `ReactTransitionGroup`.
And from the [official docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#rendering-a-different-component):

> By default `ReactTransitionGroup` renders as a span.

You can change this behavior, and render as another type of component, but this would mean you have to manually configure and render the `ReactTransitionGroup`.
This may save you one wrapper element in the DOM, but this depends on your component tree structure.

Comment: although it doesn't make sense, default wrapper should be din instead of span. Someome might want to animate the divs, and rendering div inside this ghost span breaks the html validation

Comment: You're right that it would break HTML validation. But any animations would still work (provided you have the right styling in your Css). No idea why they chose `<span>`. You can change it though.

Comment: used component: 'div' to paint div instead of span

Comment: so now you should have `<div>` instead of `<span>`, but at least it is no longer mysterious :)